# Lots of dependences went to point: Could not find class [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory] and it cant be added to pom.xml cause cant be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, neo4j

Its chat bot on telegram api. Wanted to add registration and users bd. Done all by some guide. Had no errors with import while writing. But in Run started getting lots of errors:

First was: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory]
I added it.

Then: org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.JdbcRepositoryConfigExtensio - it was also added.

Then: org.neo4j/neo4j-ogm was also added ... aaand thats how i got to point where nothing works cause there is   [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Main]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory] - and there is no "SessionFactory" on Maven.

What should I add to have help?

My main is:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>WTG_tgbot</groupId>
 <artifactId>WTG_tgbot</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
         <source>8</source>
         <target>8</target>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
 </build>

 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb -->
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jdbc -->
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-ogm -->
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.8</version>
     <type>pom</type>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
     <artifactId>telegrambots-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
     <version>4.6</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
     <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.200</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
   <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
     <version>1.6</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>oro</groupId>
     <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.8</version>
   </dependency>

     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.2</version>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Add in the .jar file to your external library?

Comment: *.jar files of what?

Comment: Stackoverflow helping 10/10.
@C2H50H there is no "Session Factory" class on maven. What should I add?